# How to use reduce function in swift for generic array?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I have a generic array.

```
let array = arrayOfElements as! [T]
```

I want to add elements of the array using `reduce` function of Swift. How can I do this?

I am doing this.

```
let result = array.reduce(0, +)
```

It shows error

> ambiguous reference to member '+'

Comment: Have a look at Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce

Comment: Could you describe in detail what you want to achieve?
For now, you probably get that error, because the compiler does not know what T is, and if + is appliable to elements of type T. Anyway, that does not look like adding element to the array. It reduces the array to the single value (as the 'reduce' name implies).

Comment: How would you expect the compiler to be able to sum a generic type?

Comment: You `T` should have `+`

Comment: Your generic Type would need to be constrained to the Numeric protocol

Comment: What is T in your code? Could it be an array?

Answer (score 2):

How do you know that `T` is a type that can be added? `T` can be anything, can't it? What if `T` is `Bool`? `True` and `False` values can certainly not be added.

To be able to add `T`s, the range of possible types for `T` must be limited. `T` must conform to the `Numeric` protocol. Since the `Numeric` protocol defines a `+` operator, we can be sure that whatever `T` is, as long as it conforms to `Numeric`, it can be added.

You could do something like this:

```
func sum<T: Numeric>(_ array: [T]) -> T {
    return array.reduce(0, +)
}
```

Or an extension:

```
extension Sequence where Element : Numeric {
    func sum() -> Element {
        return reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

Note that in both cases, I have put a `: Numeric` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. T can be any type, including types that don’t have the + operator and/or can’t be created from the integer literal 0. Those requirements are provided by the Numeric protocol, so you can define your type parameter as `<T: Numeric>` to make this work